# What is the name of this kind of route?

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I was just reading through [a Compojure tutorial](http://techbehindtech.com/category/clojure/) and saw this route example:

```
(GET "/addresses/:id" [id] (json-response (address/find id)))
```

I was wondering what is a proper official name for the kind of route where the part of path is the parameter, rather than an actual HTTP parameter (GET or POST)

I know what it does. I'd like to know what is its name. The best I could think of is friendly URL, although that is quite vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Clean URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL)

Or sometimes referred to as a "RESTful" url as they often go hand in hand with the [REST style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) of web development